# Classic method throwing AbstractMethodError VS abstract method

Tags: java, enums, abstract

I just had a look on the [TimeUnit enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) source code (simplified herebelow):

```java
public enum TimeUnit {

    SECONDS {
        public long toMillis(long d) { return d * 1000L; }
    },
    MINUTES {
        public long toMillis(long d) { return d * 60000L; }
    };

    public long toMillis(long duration) {
        throw new AbstractMethodError();
    }

}
```

They could also have implemented it using an abstract method:

```java
public enum TimeUnit {

    SECONDS {...}, MINUTES {...};

    public abstract long toMillis(long duration);

}
```

Since they chose the first implementation, I guess there must be a reason why. Thus, my question is: why? Can the `AbstractMethodError` be ever thrown? If yes, in which case(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard doclet (i.e. the Sun/Oracle variety) does not present `abstract` enum methods in Javadoc output. If these methods were abstract, the Javadoc would show no trace of them. This bug is still open and was originally reported in 2005 (9+ years ago):

JDK-6287639 : Abstract methods in enum classes should not be listed as abstract
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6287639

If the correct behavior were to be implemented, these methods would appear in the Javadoc output with the abstract keyword stripped off. Enum values are essentially anonymous subclasses of the enum class so javac ensures that enum values implement every abstract method. As such, abstract enum methods are effectively non-abstract from the perspective of an external observer.

The following comment written in the implementation of TimeUnit provides a bit more insight:

> ```
> // To maintain full signature compatibility with 1.5, and to improve the
> // clarity of the generated javadoc (see 6287639: Abstract methods in
> // enum classes should not be listed as abstract), method convert
> // etc. are not declared abstract but otherwise act as abstract methods.
> ```

If Javadoc is important to your project, you may want to consider following in TimeUnit's footsteps.

Answer (score 1):

The exception can only be thrown of one of the enum values fails to override the method, or if it calls up to the superclass method. I don't recommend that particular approach; much better to let the compiler catch those errors, as your suggested alternative would accomplish.

By the way, the `toMillis` implementation for `MINUTES` sure looks wrong to me. That isn't the implementation in the Java 7 sources that I have. Where did you find it?

P.S. I just checked: the Android implementation of `TimeUnit` does not use `AbstractMethodError`, but neither does it use abstract methods. It uses a variety of tables and implements all the conversion methods at the `enum` level.

Comment: You're right about the `MINUTES` `toMillis` implementation, I've just edited.